# Discord.py: How do I get a member object from a user object?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have a user object, but I want to access their nickname in a guild, which I also have.
Is there any way of doing this? Or am I completely of track.

Thanks.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def test(ctx,id):
  name = ctx.author.guild.get_member(id).nick
  return name
```

The Error is: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nick'`

Comment: You're gonna need to get the guild instance, then you can use the `Guild.get_member` method

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work, as you can see above.

Comment: You need to enable `intents.members` also when in `Guild.get_member` method you're supposed to pass an ID not the whole `discord.User` instance

Comment: Same Error although I enabled intents in the Developer Portal.

Comment: You also need to enable them in your code.

Comment: didnt I do that?

Comment: You need to pass them into the bot constructor, thing that you didn't

Comment: how exactly do I do that?

Comment: `client = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-converters) so you can immediately get a user object. This would accept `id`, `mention` and `name` as arguments.

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    if user.nick == None:
        await ctx.send(f"Display name: {user.display_name}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Nickname: {user.nick}")
```

[image: Working as seen here]

---

However, if you want to use the code that you provided, you'll need to convert your `id` into an `int`. This is assuming the user has a nickname, though. If the the user does not have a nickname, it will return `None`.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx, id:int):
    name = ctx.author.guild.get_member(id).nick
    await ctx.send(name)
```

[image: Using the given code]