# How to mention a user without putting id after command in server

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def status(current, content: str):
    status = None
    for member in current.guild.members:
        if str(member.id) == content:
            status = member.status
            break
    if status == discord.Status.online:
        online_embed = discord.Embed(
            title="awa is online", description="", color=0xF6E5E5
        )
        await current.send(embed=online_embed)
```

I would have to do #status [user id] every time, is there a way to make it #status only?

Comment: You are asking this question the third time now, why not wait until you get help under one of your other questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to get a member object in a command, allowing you to use a user's id, their name, etc., would be to use the converter they provide.

```py
@client.command()
async def test(current, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member == None: # if no member is provided..
        member = current.author # ..make member the author
    await current.send(f"Hello {member.mention}!")
```

[image: Above code working]

**Other questions like this**:

- [Discord.py get user object from id/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54500251/14420546)
- [Discord.py: How do I get a member object from a user object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66084857/14420546)